# How to handle failed asserts and abort calls with Microsofts unit testing framework?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, unit-testing, assert

I just moved from my catch2 testing frameworks to Microsofts native code C++ unit testing framework for the nicer integration into the IDE.

But my coding style is to use lots of assert statements all over the code. I cant replace them with macro calls like AssertIfTrue calls without poisoning the whole codebase with dependencies to the framework.

But if an assert fails the unit test runner stops with message box popup and when i press abort button the test will be reported as skipped and not as failed. This also looks like impossible behaviour for any automated continuous integration lifecycle.

I already tried setting a signal handler via `signal(SIGABRT, SignalHandler);` but the handler is never called. And using _set_abort_behavior to disable the message box with  `_set_abort_behavior( 0, _WRITE_ABORT_MSG);` also has no result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the solution after stepping through the source code.
This fragment must be put in some initialization routine before running the code.

```
#include "CppUnitTest.h"

static void my_abort_function(int signo) {
    Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework::Assert::IsTrue(false);    
}

void initialize() noexcept {    
    _set_error_mode(_OUT_TO_STDERR);
    _set_abort_behavior(0, _WRITE_ABORT_MSG);
    signal(SIGABRT, my_abort_function);
}
```